# XP Common Controls Manifest: processorArchitecture='x86' vs. processorArchitecture='*'

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, manifest, common-controls

What's the advantage of saying

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32'"  \
     "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'"               \
     "version='6.0.0.0'"                                      \
     "processorArchitecture='x86'"                            \
     "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

instead of

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32'"  \
     "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls'"               \
     "version='6.0.0.0'"                                      \
     "processorArchitecture='*'"                              \
     "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

when specifing a manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `x86` means that the manifest cannot be used if you target 64 bit platforms. I'd say that this was a disadvantage. I think using `*` is better.